# How to use WIA vesion 2 in win 7 and c#?

Tags: c#, wia, image-scanner

I am using c# 2008 and wanna to capture a picture from scanner but i cant use WIA v2 in win7 and the TWAIN component in XP doesnt support win7 please help me how to do that
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssdk/thread/98c5dd87-1359-4c35-bc77-af3c20aad85c?

Referencing Wiaaut.dll seems to work for me.